# Accessing data members of a data member(itself is object) as if they were class members

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

Given the scenerio,

```
template <bool T>
struct A{
    struct B{
       int x; 
       double y;
    }
    struct C{
       char c;
       std::string k;
    }
 using type = std::conditional<T, B, C>::type;
 type b;
}
```

I would like to access to data members such as:

```
int main(){
    A<true> object_1;
    A<false> object_2;
    cout << object_1.x;
    cout << object_2.k;
}
```

This would be possible if `.`(dot) operator could be overloaded. However, this is not possible(at least now). Is there a workaround to make the example work?

Comment: Make a reference member in `A` that refers to the sub object member?

Comment: struct b does not stay the same. It can be another struct, that is declared in A, and having different number of data members with different types. I will update it to make it more concrete. (Example Updated)

Comment: Having the ability to overload `.` operator would just be perfect.

Comment: Is it okay if the solution adds to the size of `A` and using the members this way is not exactly as efficient as direct member access?

Comment: @aschepler struct size or efficiency is not a concern. Simplicity in syntax is what I need at this point.

Comment: Hmm, this is trickier than I thought. A reference member won't play nice with `const`. A proxy member (besides doing strange things in some template and `auto` cases) would itself run into trouble allowing a second dot operator like `object_2.k.c_str()`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overload `.`, that is correct. You can, however, overload `->`, if that is also an option for you?

`operator->` must return a type that itself supports `operator->`, e.g. a raw pointer suits this:

```
template <bool T> struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        int x; 
        double y; 
    }; 
    struct C
    { 
        char c; 
        std::string k;
    };
    using type = std::conditional<T, B, C>::type;
    type b;

    type* operator->() { return &b; }
};
```

You can use it like so:

```
int main()
{ 
    A<true> object_1; 
    A<false> object_2; 
    cout << object_1->x; 
    cout << object_2->k;
}
```

Comment: better would be the `.` syntax.

Comment: @nmd_07 Well, as you said by yourself, this is impossible. May I ask why `->` isn't working for you? Are you using `A` as a pointer?

Comment: It would be more convenient to use `.` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it is easier than I thought :

```
struct B{
    int x; 
    double y;
}
struct C{
   char c;
   std::string k;
}
template <bool T>
struct A : public std::conditional <T, B, C>::type{

}
```